# Where does the transaction fee go after balance transfer without a treasury pallet in solo chain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, transaction-fees

I am using [Substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) for my application. I have added custom pallet.

This is a solo chain. I just want to know where transaction fee goes after a successful balance transfer. I have read [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/337/where-do-the-transaction-fees-go-to) that For Polkadot and Kusama, 80% of the transaction fees go to the treasury, and 20% go to the block producer. But I don't have treasury pallet integrated in my runtime.

Can somebody please tell where does it to go without a treasury pellet? Does 100% go to block producer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the node template.

It uses [`CurrencyAdapter<Balance, ()>`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/87b1b4728e29f68c6b2bafde7f3d0f4c8af9b302/runtime/src/lib.rs#L258).

The second parameter is `()` instead of a treasury instance, which means the fee will be burned.

Check https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_transaction_payment/struct.CurrencyAdapter.html and https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/imbalance/trait.OnUnbalanced.html#impl-OnUnbalanced%3CImbalance%3E-for-().

Comment: which means fee will go nowhere and no-one gets the fee? Please correct if I am missing anything.

Comment: Yep. The token is burned/removed from the system.